# Completing an orthonormal basis of a plane to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I was asked to find an orthonormal basis for the plane $x + 2y +3z =0$.
I found a regular basis, $(-2,1,0),(-3,0,1)$, and then performed the Gram-Schmidt process to find 2 orthonormal vectors that span the plane. I got the vectors $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-2,1,0), \frac{1}{\sqrt{70}}(-3,-6,5)$.

Then, I was asked to complete the basis to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, I am looking for a vector $(x,y,z)$ such that $(x,y,z)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-2,1,0) = 0,\ (x,y,z)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{70}}(-3,-6,5) = 0,\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

From the first 2 equations, I made a system, and after reducing I got the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0\\
-3 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
After looking, I realized that the rows of this matrix are the original basis I found for the plane.

Does this happen for a reason or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

What you notice is not a coincidence. It is just a consequence of the way the dot product is expressed using the vector coordinates.

And your last vector is the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the previous two. Which avoids the computation you mention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At this point in my studying, we have yet to define the cross product. So basically, there is nothing deep in the fact that the matrix I got is the original basis I created?

Comment: (+1) @JonTrav: To elaborate on this (good) answer, if the third vector is $n = (x, y, z)$, each row of your matrix asserts that $n$ is orthogonal to a basis vector of the plane you started with. A vector orthogonal to all (i.e., both) basis vectors is consequently orthogonal to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

the vector $\pmatrix{1,&0,&0}^\top$ is not on the plane $x + 2y + 3z = 0.$ 
i can project this vector onto the normal to the plane and get the third ortonormal vector to complete the basis you have.

so $$(1,0,0)^\top = k(1,2,3) + b$$ choose $k$ so that $b$ is orthogonal to $(1,2,3)^\top.$ taking the dot product give you $k = \frac1{14}.$ so 
$$b = \frac{1}{14}\pmatrix{13,&-2, &-3}.$$ make the vector $b$ of length $1.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am aware how to find another vector. I was just wondering if there is any connection between the matrix I got and the original basis I chose for the plane?

Comment: @JonTrav,  the third vector must be in the null space of the matrix you got. that would be another way to get the third vector.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you perform Gram-Schmidt again?

If $u$ and $v$ are the vectors of the orthonormal basis of the plane, choose any $a$ that is not in the plane, and set 
$$b=a-\langle a,u\rangle u-\langle a,v\rangle v,$$ then normalise:
$$w=\frac b{\lVert b\rVert}.$$